# Usage of 'Queries' or 'Questions' in Academia Tag Wikis?

Tags: discussion, tags

After reviewing and editing a few of the [tags wikis in the SE.Academia, many of the excerpts seem to be split between the use of either 'Queries' or 'Questions'](https://academia.stackexchange.com/tags). As I am updated the Wikis I have been unifying the word 'Questions' as it seems more international contrasted to the localized 'queries' terminology. Should these two words be combined into one or the other? and if so, should it be 'questions' or 'queries'?

Comment: P.S. regarding the votes on this question, note that they probably express disagreement with the idea of standardizing on "queries" or "questions", not that this is a bad question (it's a perfectly good question for meta). See [voting is different on meta](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 5):

> Should these two words be combined into one or the other?

I don't see any reason why they should. There's no rule that tag wiki excerpts all have to "match"; if two words work equally well, either one is fine to use.

> should it be 'questions' or 'queries'?

Neither.

You have 500 characters to help someone understand how to use the tag. Do you really need to waste space telling them that the tag is for questions, when *all* tags are for questions?

Also see [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)